# Create a new instance of a type given as parameter

Tags: vb.net

I've searched for an answer and found some c#-examples, but could not get this running in vb.net:

I thought of something like the following:

```
public function f(ByVal t as System.Type)
  dim obj as t
  dim a(2) as t

  obj = new t
  obj.someProperty = 1
  a(0) = obj

  obj = new t
  obj.someProperty = 2
  a(1) = obj

  return a
End Function
```

I know, I can create a new instance with the Activator.Create... methods, but how to create an array of this type or just declare a new variable? (dim)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It really depends on the type itself. **If the type is a reference type and has an empty constructor** (a constructor accepting zero arguments), the following code should create an insance of it:
Using Generics:

```
Public Function f(Of T)() As T
    Dim tmp As T = GetType(T).GetConstructor(New System.Type() {}).Invoke(New Object() {})
    Return tmp
End Function
```

Using a type parameter:

```
Public Function f(ByVal t As System.Type) As Object
    Return t.GetConstructor(New System.Type() {}).Invoke(New Object() {})
End Function
```

Comment: @M.A. Hanin's answer is great, definitely use the generic version if you can. Instead of .Invoke(New Object()) I think you need to use .Invoke(Nothing). Also, all this said, 99% of the times I see someone doing this they're doing it for the wrong reason or are doing something the really, really hard way. Reflection is useful in a handful of situations but more often than not it just makes your code that much more confusing.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I needed!
I'm still trying to get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386690/method-to-override-shared-members-in-child-classes/2387070 working, so this seems to be a solution.

Comment: @Stex, glad I could help. Concerning that other question, I'ev proposed another solution, but now I see that it might be irrelevant.
@Chris Haas, thank you for your comment. I think you're right about those 99% - working with Generics and Reflection just seems too lucrative, though many times it turns out being an overkill / overcomplexation.

Answer (score 18):

Personaly I like this syntax much more.

```
Public Class Test(Of T As {New})
    Public Shared Function GetInstance() As T
        Return New T
    End Function
End Class
```

Or if you want to limit the possible types:

```
Public Class Test(Of T As {New, MyObjectBase})
    Public Shared Function GetInstance() As T
        Return New T
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Yup, this is much better