# How can I create a generic constructor? (ie. BaseClass.FromXml(<param>)

Tags: vb.net, constructor, factory-pattern, factory-method

I'm not sure how to describe this but I'm trying to create a base class that contains a shared (factory) function called FromXml.  I want this function to instantiate an object of the **proper type** and then fill it via an XmlDocument.

For example, let's say I have something like this:

```
Public Class XmlObject
    Public Shared Function FromXml(ByVal source as XmlDocument) As XmlObject
        // <need code to create SPECIFIC TYPE of object and return it
    End Function
End Class

Public Class CustomObject
    Inherits XmlObject
End Class
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
Dim myObject As CustomObject = CustomObject.FromXml(source)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to tell a function to do something with a specific type, just add generic parameters to it.  Not sure if this is the best way to go about your original intent, but it will get the job done.

```
   Public Class XmlObject
      Public Shared Function FromXml(Of T)(ByVal source As XmlDocument) As T
         Dim result As T = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T))

         Return result
      End Function
   End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the FromXml function must know the type of object it needs to create and return.
To do that, you could either:

Pass the type itself as a parameter:

```
Public Shared Function FromXml(ByVal source As XmlDocument, _
                               ByVal resultType As Type) As XmlObject
End Function
```

Use Generics:

```
Public Shared Function FromXml(Of T)(ByVal source As XmlDocument) As XmlObject

End Function
```

*(Using Generics, you can also specify, for example, "Of T as XmlObject", to only recieve in T a class assignable to XmlObject).*

Next, you'll have to decide how to instantiate a new object of the passed type.
You can either investigate the exact type passed and create a new instance accordingly (hard-coded), or use Reflection to invoke a constructor method of the passed type (assuming it has a an accessable constructor)(see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396861/create-a-new-instance-of-a-type-given-as-parameter/2396897#2396897)). This may prove a bit tricky, because if T has no empty constructors then you'll have to investigate the constructors' arguments and invoke a matchin delegate (again, using Reflection).

Comment: Nice. I actually didn't know you could restrict the generic parameter to a specific class.  That would have saved me lots of silly "If TryCast..." code.

Comment: It works well, you can restrict to interfaces, and make generic restrictions (Class SomeClass(of TBase)... Function myFunc(of T as TBase), etc. etc.

I didn't know anything about Activator.CreateInstance, I'll check it out :-)