# "Public \ Friend" vs "Friend \ Friend"

Tags: vb.net, friend, access-modifiers, internal

I've been reading about access modifiers in VB.Net lately, and there is something that I can't really understand: How do elements in a `Class` (or `Module`) inherit the modifiers of their enclosing block?

For example, suppose you have a `Friend` class `Bla` in an assembly, with a public method `Foo`:

```
Friend Class Bla
    Public Sub Foo
    (...)
End Class
```

Does it behave differently than when `Foo` is set to Friend? If so, which one do you advise?

```
Friend Class Bla
    Friend Sub Foo
    (...)
End Class
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't your title suggesting that your second code-block should be Public Class Bla and Friend Sub Foo?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652564/please-explain-behavior-when-class-and-member-have-different-access/5655177#5655177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it doesn't matter whether one specified `public` or `Friend` for `Foo` because the enclosing class is available only in this assembly.

One can choose to restrict the access modifier for a method/property than that of the class. In your example, the method `Foo` can be private` as well, which means the method won't be available to callers, including other classes in the same assembly.

One can access methods through class/instance. If the class is `private`, what use is a `public` method?

EDIT: On a side note, it is possible for you to return an instance of `Bla` to the caller (which is in other assembly). In that case, the caller should be able to call `public` method, if `Foo` is declared `public`. This is my assumption.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Of course, with a private class, a public method would hardly make any sense (at least, not that I know of ;)

Comment: @shahkalpesh: It is not possible to pass an instance of `Bla` to another assembly if `Bla` has a `Friend` modifier. Your best way of achieving this is through reflection.

Comment: This is a rather aged topic, but I wanted to mention that a Public member in a Private class can be very useful - for example within a module.  The class is Private to that module, and it's Public members are accessible to the module. The class Private members however, are not available to the module outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

If someone does jump through the reflection hoops required to access `Bla`, they don't need to do so again to then call `Public Sub Foo`, but they do for `Friend Sub Foo`.